# How to perfectly grep messages from mailq only with "!" status

Tags: bash

How I can perfectly grep mailq messages with all details(X lines) only messages which ID have in ID "!" (eg. 46fMBX4LJgzKkjJ!)

Example output of mailq

```
4Ds7y78zb1zKmh2      12796 Thu Mar  4 13:01:40 example@domain.com
(host example.domain.com [XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX] said: 450 4.7.1 <example@domain.com>: Recipient address rejected: Sender address deferred by rule #CR-IN-DEF-2 #2 (in reply to RCPT TO command))
                                               example@domain.com

4DsGss5L4bzKmF3!     36254 Fri Mar  5 09:50:49 example@domain.com
                                               example2@domain.com
                                               example3@domain.com
                                               example4@domain.com
```

And I need grep only lines which ID has at the end "!" but I need extract all lines like example0-4 because it is possible that there will be many more records at this point.

Comment: Please, post some sample data with the expected output. Don't post them as comments or images but edit them to your original post. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, edited with example what I need.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with the mailq format but if it's blank line separated like in your sample, this awk should do it:

```
$ awk -v RS= '$1~/\!$/' file
```

Output:

```
4DsGss5L4bzKmF3!     36254 Fri Mar  5 09:50:49 example@domain.com
                                               example2@domain.com
                                               example3@domain.com
                                               example4@domain.com
```

https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Multiple-Line.html: *an empty string as the value of RS indicates that records are separated by one or more blank lines. When RS is set to the empty string, each record always ends at the first blank line encountered. The next record doesn’t start until the first nonblank line that follows.*

Then we just examine if the first field ends with an `!`.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this in awk:

```
$ awk '$0 !~ /^[[:space:]]/  { if ($1 ~ /!$/) p=1; else p=0; } p' < test.txt
4DsGss5L4bzKmF3!     36254 Fri Mar  5 09:50:49 example@domain.com
                                               example2@domain.com
                                               example3@domain.com
                                               example4@domain.com
```

`$0 !~ /^[[:space:]]/` checks for lines that do not start with a space. For them, `if ($1 ~ /!$/)` checks if the first field ends with a `!`. If it does, `p` is set to one, if not, `p` is set to zero. Then finally print all lines based on `p`.